# Insert XML Value/Element with Python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I've been looking all over for a solution to adding an element/value to a current XML file. So let's assume I have the following XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Node>
        <Name>Sprinkler</Name>
        <Type>Blah</Type>
        <Prob>0.82</Prob>
    </Node>
    <Node>
        <Name>Rain</Name>
        <Type>Bleh</Type>
        <Prob>0.23</Prob>
    </Node>
    <Node>
        <Name>Cloudy</Name>
        <Type>Bluh</Type>
        <Prob>0.71</Prob>
    </Node>
</Root>
```

Now, my goal is, given a CSV file, I want to add new elements and values per Node. Let's say that my CSV contains something like this:

```
Cloudy,Or,Sprinkler,Rain
Sprinkler,And,Rain
Rain,Or,Sprinkler,Cloudy
```

I was able to read the CSV without a problem, my problem is adding new elements, 'Parent0' and 'Parent1'(If any), so that the output looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Node>
        <Name>Sprinkler</Name>
        <Type>Blah</Type>
        <Prob>0.82</Prob>
        <Gate>And</Gate>
        <Parent0>Rain</Parent0>
    </Node>
    <Node>
        <Name>Rain</Name>
        <Type>Bleh</Type>
        <Prob>0.23</Prob>
        <Gate>Or</Gate>
        <Parent0>Sprinkler</Parent0>
        <Parent1>Cloudy</Parent1>
    </Node>
    <Node>
        <Name>Cloudy</Name>
        <Type>Bluh</Type>
        <Prob>0.71</Prob>
        <Gate>Or</Gate>
        <Parent0>Sprinkler</Parent0>
        <Parent1>Rain</Parent1>
    </Node>
</Root>
```

So far I have written the following in Python:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = ET.parse('XML.xml')
for row in xml.iterfind('Node'):
    i = 1
    for item in csvFile:
        row.append('<Gate>'+item[1]+'</Gate>\n')
        if i != 1:
            for x in xrange(0, len(item):
                if row.findtext('Name') == item[x]:
                    row.append('<Parent0>'+item[x]+'</Parent0>\n')
        else:
            i = 0
```

On my code it will all go to Parent0 for now, but I wanted to see how it is possible to do the append, without deleting everything? I have a heard of lxml and minidom but not sure how these work. If I am able to do it using xml.etree.ElementTree, that would be fantastic.

Comment: Forgive me, but you improperly mentioned attributes in your title and post when you really meant elements: `<element attribute = "attributevalue">elementvalue</element>`. You are trying to add new elements, `Gate`, `Parent0`, and `Parent1` and values not attributes and values. Sorry this seems picky but Python code changes slightly between the two.

Comment: Thanks, @Parfait. Yes, you are correct! I usually get confused by both. But yes, I was referring to element, not an attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to do this would be to use [`ElementTree.SubElement()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.SubElement) to create the elements, it would automatically add those elements to the end of the parent node, which is passed in as argument.

Example/Demo -

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> import csv
>>> with open('test.csv','r') as f:
...     cfiles = list(csv.reader(f))
...
>>> xml = ET.parse('XML.xml')
>>> for row in xml.iterfind('.//Node'):
...     name = row.find('./Name').text
...     for i in cfiles:
...         if i[0] == name:
...             j = 1
...             while j < len(i):
...                 if j == 1:
...                     g = ET.SubElement(row,'Gate')
...                     g.text = i[j]
...                 elif j == 2:
...                     g = ET.SubElement(row,'Parent0')
...                     g.text = i[j]
...                 elif j == 3:
...                     g = ET.SubElement(row,'Parent1')
...                     g.text = i[j]
...                 j += 1
...
>>> print(ET.tostring(xml.getroot()).decode())
<Root>
    <Node>
        <Name>Sprinkler</Name>
        <Type>Blah</Type>
        <Prob>0.82</Prob>
    <Gate>And</Gate><Parent0>Rain</Parent0></Node>
    <Node>
        <Name>Rain</Name>
        <Type>Bleh</Type>
        <Prob>0.23</Prob>
    <Gate>Or</Gate><Parent0>Sprinkler</Parent0><Parent1>Cloudy</Parent1></Node>
    <Node>
        <Name>Cloudy</Name>
        <Type>Bluh</Type>
        <Prob>0.71</Prob>
    <Gate>Or</Gate><Parent0>Sprinkler</Parent0><Parent1>Rain</Parent1></Node>
</Root>
```

Here above , `cfiles` is a list I have previously created from the csv file.

---

For writing the xml to a new document, do -

```
with open('newxml.xml','w') as of:
    of.write(ET.tostring(xml.getroot()).decode())
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, @Anand! I was actually looking for the SubElement functionality, I just wasn't able to find it. I thought it was append for some reason. This makes is so easy! Thanks again

Comment: how would you take this and save it to XML document? I tried getting the print statement you wrote and writing it on a new document, but it doesn't work. Is there a way to do so?